# Why is the › right angle quote (&rsaquo;) not vertically aligned?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-size

I tried to write the title the best as possible but I'm not sure how to accurately describe what's happening here so feel free to correct it.

I wanted to use the › right angle quote (›) instead of the > right angle quote (>), and while the › character is shorter than the > it sits at the bottom of the line, similar to a period (.). This makes it difficult to vertically align the character and when I set it to 42px it is noticeable.

Is there any other character I can use or any way I can vertically align this? It could possibly be my font but I'm not using anything special.

Example of the two characters are below. The first one is the > regular right angle bracket and the second one is the › right angle bracket that sits at the bottom.

[image: > character - vertically aligned]
[image: › character - sitting on the bottom]

Comment: I'm absolutely certain the alignment of characters depends entirely on how the font defines the glyph. That's why it's not vertically aligned.

Comment: Thank you; it looks like that is the only reason it appears like that. I will look into other ways to get it vertically aligned such as simply positioning it higher or using a different font.

Answer (score 3):

Try isolating the character in a `span` and use CSS properties `line-height` and `font-size`  to vertical align it.

Also, standard fonts such as: arial,​ verdana, ​etc. are properly vertical-aligned by default.

[See example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxqwEK?editors=1100)

Comment: I have played around with the isolated character using line-height but couldn't get it to work. In Arial (even in your example) the character still sits at the bottom, in verdana it is more vertically aligned but also sharper than I would like it. I guess I will try to find a font that displays it in the way that is best.

Comment: The same affect as in the example could also be replicated simply using a padding-bottom:-(x)px;, because setting the line height smaller than the font only tricks it to look vertically aligned. I wanted to avoid that which is why I asked why it was not vertically aligned, seeing if I could truly vertically align the character instead of tricking it. The real answer to my question is simply that in the Arial font, the &rsaquo; symbol is not vertically aligned. amphetamachine has put the correct answer to my question in the comments but unfortunately I can't accept his answer as it's a comment.

Answer (score 0):

As amphetamachine already answered, this depends on how the specific font you're using defines the glyph.

Best way I have found to fix this (without a hard-coded pixel offset) is to place the character into its own span, and then apply: *vertical-align: PERCENTAGE%*.  (In my case **vertical-align: 11%** worked well, but it's going to depend on the font).

Doing it as a percentage means it will retain the same position even with different font sizes.